# TypeScript - Casting to Object When Initializing Required Property with an Array Literal

Tags: casting, typescript

I'm trying to initialize an object that has an interface type with an object literal:

```
return {
            id: 0,
            name: name,
            localizedLabels: [
                {localeCd: defaultLocaleCd, label: name}
            ],
            localizedDescriptions: [],
            useForNetworkBuild: false,
            temporalSplitting: false,
            compounds: [],
            primaryElements: [],
            defaultMapIcon: null,
            defaultRegularIcon: null,
            markerColor: null,
            nodeShape: null
};
```

The type of the object is an interface I created called Entity.  It's got several parent interfaces.  The one causing the problem is the "localizedDescriptions" property of LocalizableObject (sorry for the deep hierarchy):

```
export interface Entity extends hubBase.PersistableObject, 
                                hubLocalization.LocalizableObject, 
                                hubBase.GraphicallyDisplayable {
    name: string;
    useForNetworkBuild: boolean;
    temporalSplitting: boolean;
    compounds: Compound[];
    primaryElements: Element[];
}
export interface LocalizedLabel extends hubBase.PersistableObject {
    localeCd: string
    label: string;
}

export interface LocalizedDescription extends hubBase.PersistableObject {
    localeCd: string
    description: string;
}

export interface LocalizableObject {
    label?: string;
    localizedLabels: LocalizedLabel[];
    description?: string;
    localizedDescriptions: LocalizedDescription;
}
```

The compiler is giving an error about the "localCd" property not being available, complaining about the `[]` initializer for "localizedDescriptions":

I tried to casting the entire object literal to `Entity`.  I also tried to put a cast before the `[]` in the assignment to "localizedDescriptions".  The error persists.  Is there a way to cast this property to remove this error?

I'm using TypeScript 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface LocalizableObject {
    label?: string;
    localizedLabels: LocalizedLabel[];
    description?: string;

    // Not an array type, did you mean LocalizedDescription[] ?
    localizedDescriptions: LocalizedDescription;
}
```

Comment: Let me just say:  Doh!